# Flutter firebase messaging - message after 5 minutes

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

My first post was: "I don't receive a message from Firebase messaging"

After I waited a couple of minutes, the message appeared on my physical device, where I build the app in release mode. So my new topic is: "I receive it but after 5 minutes and not in debug mode - does anybody know why?"

The old topic is below:

["solved"]

I created a brand-new project, did everything exactly like in several tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJA09GwURtk
or: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/

and I still don't recieve any messages when I create a campaign inside my console (Engage -> Cloud Messaging -> Compose notification) and no errors (expect:

```
E/SurfaceSyncer(13521): Failed to find sync for id=1
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver(13521): broadcast received for message
I/flutter (13521): onMessage:
[log] W/FirebaseMessaging(13521): Unable to log event: analytics library is missing
onMessage: Instance of 'RemoteMessage'
W/FirebaseMessaging(13521): Unable to log event: analytics library is missing
D/EGL_emulation(13521): app_time_stats: avg=73722.07ms min=283.28ms max=147160.86ms count=2
```

but I receive this error even I don't send a notification). It's just silent.

This is my main.dart:

```
 Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(message) async {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
    }
    
    Future<void> main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    
      NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
        alert: true,
        announcement: false,
        badge: true,
        carPlay: false,
        criticalAlert: false,
        provisional: false,
        sound: true,
      );
    
      if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
        print('User granted permission');
      } else if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
        print('User granted provisional permission');
      } else {
        print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
      }
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
```

I tried it with the initializing-flutterfire  (https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#initializing-flutterfire) steps and without it. In both scenarios it doesn't work. I also tried different emulators and my physical phone. Still no notification and no errors.

When I start the app for the first time, this messages appear:

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\Installationsdatei\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-14.2.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Is this the problem? :D

Comment: Are the messages received when the app is backgrounded? I'm asking this becase in the code you posted I don't see a call to "FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen". See this for reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#foreground_messages

Comment: Strange, I didn't use the call but receive messages as I mentioned. They are just delayed

Comment: are they still delayed? or did that happen only at the beginning?